# Uniformly colorize perfectly flat surfaces (contiguous pixels) in geotiff file in R

Tags: r, gis, gdal

I am using RGDAL to read in and plot a geotiff file:

```
df.gtiff = readOGR("/df.tif")
image(df.gtiff, red=1, green=2, blue=3)
```

The map contains some perfectly flat surfaces which are either lakes or ocean-sections, i.e. there are patches where contiguous pixels have the same elevation. Is there any way to identify these patches, say as polygons, so that I can color them uniformly (to blue, for example)? [Note: the file is too large to upload, so `gdalinfo(df.tif)` is given below):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ~/df.tif
Size is 2928, 2285
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (81.381111111111110,22.564444444444447)
Pixel Size = (0.002083333333333,-0.002083333333333)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  81.3811111,  22.5644444) ( 81d22'52.00"E, 22d33'52.00"N)
Lower Left  (  81.3811111,  17.8040278) ( 81d22'52.00"E, 17d48'14.50"N)
Upper Right (  87.4811111,  22.5644444) ( 87d28'52.00"E, 22d33'52.00"N)
Lower Right (  87.4811111,  17.8040278) ( 87d28'52.00"E, 17d48'14.50"N)
Center      (  84.4311111,  20.1842361) ( 84d25'52.00"E, 20d11' 3.25"N)
Band 1 Block=2928x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=2928x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=2928x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: What do your bands represent?

Comment: Not sure. The data is GMTED2010.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to do

```
image( df.gtiff , col = rep( "cornflowerblue" , ncell(df.gtiff) ) )
```

But in case that doesn't work, here are some worked examples:

```
require( raster )

#  Observe difference between a brick and a raster
logoB <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
logoR <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

#  Use a brick and plotRGB to get intended colours (image uses heat.colors)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image( logoR , axes = FALSE , labels = FALSE )
plotRGB( logoB )
```

[image]

```
#  To manually mask and colour to a single value:
#  This file doesn't have NA values so setting e.g. plot( logoR , col = "blue" ) won't work...

#  Example of cell values for background colour
logoB[1]
     red green blue
[1,] 255   255  255

#  Make binary mask with some threshold of 'close to white' or 'close to black' values
newLogo <- calc( logoB , function(x) sum( x ) < 725 + 0 | sum( x ) < 50 + 0 )

#  Then plot, supplying a colour for each binary level
plot(newLogo , col = c( "white" , "cornflowerblue" ) , main = "binary mask" )
```

[image]

```
# If your file has background cells set to NA you can just plot directly setting the colour equal to number of cells in raster:

require(maptools)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
image( r , col = rep("cornflowerblue" , ncell(r)) , axes = FALSE )
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines - but finding a threshold would probably be laborous for different lakes. One would want an algorithm that looks for "flat" surfaces, or at least their values. Interesting, but quite complex, problem.

Comment: Hi Simon... I guess I wasn't very clear with the question. I have patches where contiguous pixel elevation is the same. My problem is how to identify and colorize these patches. I am updating my question to clarify this.

Comment: I thought it was just the flat surfaces! I have an idea but on the train so will update later.

Comment: @user702432 look into using `r.watershed` which is a `GRASS` function. `GRASS` has an interface with R via the `spgrass6` package.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, SimonO101. I'll check it out and update.